# Selective marshalling object

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I need to execute a selective marshalling object. For example:

There is a class **Contact**:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "contact")
public class Contact {

    private String name;
    private String number;
    private String address;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

}
```

Marshalling the object:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {    
        Contact contact = new Contact();
        contact.setAddress("5 Av.");
        contact.setName("John");
        contact.setNumber("5555555");    

        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Contact.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.marshal(contact, System.out);
    }
```

As a result we have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<contact>
    <address>5 street</address>
    <name>John</name>
    <number>5555555</number>
</contact>
```

Is there any simple way to perform a selective marshalling? For example, only the address to get at the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<contact>
    <address>5 street</address>
</contact>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When unspecified, the default is as-if the following annotation is on the class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PUBLIC_MEMBER)
```

That means that all public member will be used by JAXB, i.e. all your getter methods.

You can either keep that default and suppress the getter methods you don't want, or you can change the default and explicitly mark the getter methods you do want processed.

To suppress a getter method, annotate with [`@XmlTransient`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlTransient.html):

> Prevents the mapping of a JavaBean property/type to XML representation.

To change default, annotate with [`@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAccessType.html#NONE):

> None of the fields or properties is bound to XML unless they are specifically annotated with some of the JAXB annotations.

Then explicitly annotate desired getter methods with [`@XmlElement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement.html):

> Maps a JavaBean property to a XML element derived from property name.

*Using `@XmlTransient`*

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "contact")
class Contact {

    private String name;
    private String number;
    private String address;

    @XmlTransient
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

}
```

*Using `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)`*

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "contact")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
class Contact {

    private String name;
    private String number;
    private String address;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

}
```

*Output (from both)*

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<contact>
    <address>5 Av.</address>
</contact>
```